# How to enable HTTP Authorization Header on the Nginx server?

Tags: wordpress, xcode, flutter, api, dart

I am trying to configure JWT Authentication for WordPress REST API. But the problem is there is no direct config available for enabling the HTTP Authorization Header. Nginx doesn't have a .htaccess file, so I can't add the rewrite rules.

Here are the rules for apache based server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

I believe it's not going to work with Nginx. What is the solution available for the Nginx side?

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: You can check here: https://github.com/usefulteam/jwt-auth/issues/61#issuecomment-1071170819

But they responded very late, so I shifted to Litespeed.